# Implicit rule for each file name, with unspecified subdirectory

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

This is the directory structure I'm trying to build into my binary.

```
library_name:
    library_module:
        foo.h
        foo.c
    library_module:
        bar.h
        bar.c
        boo.h
        boo.c
    (etc...)
```

And I'm trying to make a rule that compiles all of these into objects:

```
obj:
    foo.o
    bar.o
    boo.o
    (etc...)
```

```
LIBRARY_NAME := $(patsubst %.c, %, $(notdir $(wildcard src/library_name/**/*.c)))
# This is a list of all file names with path and extension removed.

$(LIBRARY_NAME:%=obj/%.o): obj/%.o: src/library_name/**/%.c
    $(CC) -c $< $(FLAGS) -o $@

# make: *** No rule to make target 'src/library_name/**/foo.c', needed by 'obj/foo.o'.  Stop.
```

I've also tried the following:

```
... $(wildcard src/alabaster/**/$(%).c) ...
```

But it seems I can't use '%' like that.

Maybe this isn't actually the way to go about doing this, I usually don't touch my makefile unless I really need too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do your approach, but if you ever have a file with the same name you will run into problems. It is better to keep the folder structure for your object directory. I have not tested the makefile below (but its 99% there I think). But this gives you an idea how you might achieve what you want - Note that there are duplicate names for the files in the two librarie folders...

```
# Get your source list (use wildcard or what ever, but just for clarity you should end up with a list of files with full paths to start with):
SOURCES = \
    lib1/fred.c \
    lib1/bob.c \
    lib1/carl.c \
    lib2/fred.c \
    lib2/bob.c \
    lib2/carl.c \

# Output folders/targets
OBJ_DIR = obj
BIN_DIR = bin
OUTPUT_FILE = output

# Create your objects list in the obj directory
OBJECTS = $(addprefix $(OBJ_DIR)/,$(addsuffix .o,$(basename $(SOURCES))))

# Create list of unique folders to create
DIRS = $(sort $(dir $(OBJECTS))) $(BIN_DIR)

# Create list of include paths
INCS = $(addprefix -I,$(sort $(dir $(SOURCES))))

# Main target rule
bin/$(OUTPUT_FILE): $(DIRS)  $(OBJECTS)
    @echo linker: gcc $(OBJECTS) -o $@
    @touch $@

# Rule to build your object file - ensure that the folders are created first (also create a dummy obj file) - note this works for parallel builds too (make -j
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: %.c | $(DIRS)
    @echo compile: gcc $(INCS) -c $? -o $@
    @touch $@

# Create your directories here
$(DIRS):
    @echo Creating dir: $@
    @mkdir -p $@

# Clean if needed
.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJ_DIR) $(BIN_DIR)
```

If you really want to do it your way, you will need to look at VPATH I believe - I never like doing it that way though due to the reason I mentioned before which I have hit too many times later on down the road to ever want to use again! :)

**Updated** just got home, tested this and made a few tweaks to make sure it works.